# ElasticSearch 6.0.1: .../_forcemerge API does not scale with more threads (is throttled?)

Tags: elasticsearch, merge, segment, throttling

I am using ES 6.0.1 and have to do frequent index open/append/close patterns over many indexes, typically from different clients in parallel. (Yes, I have to open and close every time)

This leads to high number of small Lucene segments per index, and the mentioned sequence becomes slower over time (2-5 times slower sometimes). Default ES segment merging  strategy apparently is not doing a great job.

When I use [Force Merge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html) API to merge segments within index, the performance of my sequence returns back to normal for processed indices. However, due to large number of indices, I have to apply it many times to handle all indices. Naturally, I run it in  multiple threads (connections), but it seems like ES never parallels this operation and the resulting rate of merge is the same, no matter how many parallel requests I make.

I've read and tried things from [here](https://www.outcoldman.com/en/archive/2017/07/13/elasticsearch-explaining-merge-settings/) but this didn't help.

Could someone kindly suggest any w/a for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change size of force_merge thread pool via elasticsearch config file, for example:

```
thread_pool.force_merge.size: 5
```

And don't forget to restart Elasticsearch after the config change.